# How to cancel ChangeDetectorRef in ngOnDestroy

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

```
  ngOnInit() {    
    this.detectChangeInterval = setInterval(
      () => {
        this.detectRef.detectChanges(); // detectRef is type ChangeDetectorRef
      }, 2000);
  }

  // After leaving this page, I got: error_handler.js:47 EXCEPTION: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges
  ngOnDestroy() {   
    if(this.detectChangeInterval) { 
      clearInterval(this.detectChangeInterval);
    }
  }
```

I assume the exception means `clearInterval(this.detectChangeInterval);` did not cancel the recursive calling of `this.detectRef.detectChanges();`

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to use different life cycle events than the default angular2 ones. Ionic2 has its own `Page` life cycle events which you can use. You can see those [**here**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/) (scroll a bit).

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
   this.detectChangeInterval = setInterval(() => {
      this.detectRef.detectChanges(); // detectRef is type ChangeDetectorRef
   }, 2000);    
}

ionViewWillLeave() {
   if(this.detectChangeInterval) { 
     clearInterval(this.detectChangeInterval);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @PierreDuc It works. Don't know why ngOnInit and ngOnDestroy do not work. I still think calling ng lifecycle is better in this case cause ion lifecycle is called even when a dialog is being displayed and dismissed. But for now it's the workaround :-D

Comment: @macio.Jun I would guess in the Page types they use, the page doesn't actually gets destroyed as it does in vanilla angular2. One of the main reasons they made those `Page` thingies is because of this. They want to keep the component alive :)